# .htm file load works in IE but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html

I need to show a .htm file, that is outside the application.

Here is design and code.

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="showhtm()">

<div id="htmldiv">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function showhtm() {
    var sPath = window.location.pathname;
    var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var shtm = sPage.substring(0, sPage.lastIndexOf('.'));

    $("#htmldiv").load("http://10.196.128.98/htms/app/files/html/" + shtm + ".htm");

}
</script>
```

This works in IE, but not in Firefox.

Should i use iframe instead.

Comment: Have you checked the console in Firebug to see if there is an error?

Comment: I guess it's because of Same Origin Policy mentioned below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I take it that code is being run *locally*, from a page loaded via a `file://` URL (e.g., that you've double-clicked or similar). The reason it works in IE but not in Firefox is that they have different interpretations of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which prevents cross-origin ajax calls. IE allows origin `null` (a local file) to load resources from the web via ajax, even though technically that's a cross-origin call, but Firefox does not.

> Should i use iframe instead.

An `iframe` would work, yes. Of course, you can't do any scripting of its content from the container page (because of the SOP again), and the page you're loading into it needs not to use frame-busting script, but given those provisos it should work. You'd set its `src` rather than using `load`, of course:

```
$("#htmliframe")[0].src = "http://10.196.128.98/htms/app/files/html/" + shtm + ".htm";
// or
$("#htmliframe").attr("src", "http://10.196.128.98/htms/app/files/html/" + shtm + ".htm");
```